# Trying to use join to aggregate data and getting odd output

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, netezza

When running this query been getting an odd error I've not yet encountered, this query is executed within Netezza

```
      SELECT    a.CALENDAR_DATE,
  b.NewBusinessUnit,
  b.ResellerID,
  b.ResellerName,
  a.PRODUCT,
  a.CLI
  FROM  
  dbo.ADMIN.ODS_DICECNT_TTB_OUTPUT_ONE a
  left inner join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_OSS_BFD_BFDAGENT AS C  A.agentid = C.AGENTID
  left inner join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_DISECNT_NETWORK_CLI_TEST  b on C.AGENTID = b.ResellerID 
  WHERE NewBusinessUnit <> 'Inter-Co'
  AND b.NewBusinessUnit = 'Business Wholesale'
```

which produces the following error

Status: ERROR

---

SELECT  a.CALENDAR_DATE,
b.NewBusinessUnit,
b.ResellerID,
b.ResellerName,
a.PRODUCT,
a.CLI
FROM
dbo.ADMIN.ODS_DICECNT_TTB_OUTPUT_ONE a
left inner join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_OSS_BFD_BFDAGENT AS C  A.agentid = C.AGENTID
left inner join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_DISECNT_NETWORK_CLI_TEST  b on C.AGENTID = b.ResellerID
WHERE NewBusinessUnit <> 'Inter-Co'
AND b.NewBusinessUnit = 'Business Wholesale'

---

210ms 2023-03-24T11:36:39.077Z

---

(SQLSTATE: HY000, SQLCODE: 1100): ERROR:  'SELECT   a.CALENDAR_DATE, b.NewBusinessUnit, b.ResellerID, b.ResellerName, a.PRODUCT, a.CLI FROM  dbo.ADMIN.ODS_DICECNT_TTB_OUTPUT_ONE a left inner join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_OSS_BFD_BFDAGENT AS C  A.agentid = C.AGENTID left inner join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_DISECNT_NETWORK_CLI_TEST  b on C.AGENTID = b.ResellerID  WHERE NewBusinessUnit <> 'Inter-Co' AND b.NewBusinessUnit = 'Business Wholesale'' error                                                                                                                                                ^ found "INNER" (at char 141) expecting `JOIN'

Comment: It should be `left OUTER join` …and an ON is missing(?)..AS c ON.. `left outer join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_OSS_BFD_BFDAGENT AS C  on A.agentid = C.AGENTID
  left outer join ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_DISECNT_NETWORK_CLI_TEST  b on C.AGENTID = b.ResellerID `

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing called as `left inner join`

You should change it to `left join`

And `left join` is an `outer join`.

So you can even change to [left outer join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/outer-joins?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
SELECT a.CALENDAR_DATE, 
       b.NewBusinessUnit, 
       b.ResellerID, 
       b.ResellerName, 
       a.PRODUCT, 
       a.CLI 
FROM   dbo.ADMIN.ODS_DICECNT_TTB_OUTPUT_ONE a 
       LEFT JOIN ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_OSS_BFD_BFDAGENT AS C 
              ON A.agentid = C.AGENTID 
       LEFT JOIN ODS_LAYER.ADMIN.ODS_DISECNT_NETWORK_CLI_TEST b 
              ON C.AGENTID = b.ResellerID 
WHERE  NewBusinessUnit <> 'Inter-Co' 
       AND b.NewBusinessUnit = 'Business Wholesale';
```